# How to use Django __str__() method for Django Tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I would like my `django_tables2` table to show the `__str__()` formatted version of a record. Here' what I'm working with:

```
#models.py
class people(models.Model):
    namelast = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name')
    namefirst = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='First Name')
    # more fields...
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.namefirst, self.namelast)

#tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import people

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    person = tables.Column()

    def render_person(self, value, record):
        return record  #Also tried record.lastname, record.__str__()

    class Meta:
        model = people
        fields = ('person',)
```

All variations of that has just returned a table with a column named "Person" and blank lines (i.e. "_"). How can I get a column that's formatted as `namefirst namelast`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.6 and up use **f-string**, otherwise **.format**

```py
def __str__(self):
    # f-string
    return "{self.namefirst} {self.namelast}"
    # format 
    return "{} {}".format(self.namefirst, self.namelast)
```

`__str__` is used to show string representation of the object ex:
`p1 = people()` now when you print the object you get this output `print(p1) => john doe`

In meta of your **PersonTable** add the fields you want to be printed

```py
class PersonTable(tables.Table):

    def render_person(self, value, record):
        return record  #Also tried record.lastname, record.__str__()

    class Meta:
        model = people
        fields = ('namefirst', 'namelast',)
```